# OpenLayers 3 - Get applied style for rendered feature

Tags: openlayers-3

Is it possible to get the applied style for a selected feature? My layer uses a style function instead of an ol.style.Style. When I call myFeature.getStyle() it returns the function.

*Updating my question with some things that I have tried so far based on responses here and elsewhere.*

I ended up creating a select style function for each layer.

This doesn't work, no style is returned:

```
selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select( {
    style: function( feature, resolution ) {
        if ( feature.selectStyle ) {
            return feature.selectStyle;
        }
    },
    layers: mylayers
} );
```

Also, with the above I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: style.getImage is not a function
    ol.renderer.vector.renderFeature                @ol.js:38455
    ol.renderer.canvas.VectorLayer.renderFeature    @ol.js:44202
    renderFeature                                   @ol.js:44148
    ol.renderer.canvas.VectorLayer.prepareFrame     @ol.js:44164
    ol.renderer.canvas.Map.renderFrame              @ol.js:45268
    ol.Map.renderFrame_                             @ol.js:52034
    (anonymous function)                            @ol.js:50898
```

This does work, the feature is rendered using my select style. However, I don't want to have to manage re-setting styles, so it really needs to be implemented in the selectInteraction:

```
evt.selected.forEach( function( evt ) {
    evt.setStyle( evt.selectStyle );
}, this );
```

Answer (score 3):

My workaround was to create the style separately from the feature and then use setStyle() to apply it. I also saved the style elsewhere in the feature so it could be retrieved later.

```
let myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'cyan'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'black',
            width: 1
        }),
        points: 4,
        radius: 9,
        angle: Math.PI / 4
    }),
});
myFeature.setStyle(myStyle);
myFeature.set('myStyle', myStyle); // save it for later use
```

During the 'select' process simply use:

```
feature.get('myStyle');
```

to retrieve the style that was applied to the feature.

Comment: This workaround is the way! Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function with the feature (and optionally the resolution if your style function depends on it). So something like: myFeature.getStyle().call(this, feature); or myFeature.getStyle().call(this, feature, resolution);

Comment: I tried this but myFeature.getStyle() returns null. How is it that the styleFunction_ property of the feature is undefined when it has been styled?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use `myFeature.getStyleFunction()` instead of `myFeature.getStyle()`.

Good Luck.